# Second order difference equation satisfying this:

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have a second-order difference equation which satisfies the following:

$\frac{a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}}{a_{n+1}-a_{n}} = k >0$ for any $n$.

I can see that $ \Delta a_{n}\equiv a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ is satisfying an exponential relation, but what more can I say about $a_{n}$ itself?

Thank you very much

Comment: The relation can be rewritten in the form $a_{n+2} = (k+1)a_{n+1} - k a_n$ which shows that given $a_0, a_1$, every successive $a_n$ for $n \geqslant 2$ is determined.  Then the standard way of solving it is then to try $a_n = \alpha x^n$ and obtain possible values of $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I came up with that exponential solution, but it didn’t seem to be the unique solution. Is that correct? For instant $a_{n}=\alpha k^{n} + \beta k^{n-1}$ would also satisfy..

Comment: If $a_0$ and $a_1$ are given there will be just one solution.  If these are not specified the set of solutions will be fully described by linear combinations of $k^n$ and a constant (i.e. $a_n = \alpha k^n + \beta$)